# How can I trim the results of a sql query, and remove duplicates?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have a sql query that returns names, appended with the current date-time, with a period/full stop used as separator. For example, the results might look like this:

```
John.2010-10-9
Richard.2012-1-11
John.2011-1-1
```

What I want to keep is

```
John
Richard
```

How can I accomplish this? Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(columnName,1,(CHARINDEX('.', columnName) - 1))
FROM tableName
```

[**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0c287/5)

Comment: I'm using sql server so this (LOCATE) did not work for me, should work in mysql. Sorry about the incorrect tags; I've fixed them.

Comment: @Freakishly ok i have updated the answer that works on SQL Server

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(your_column, '.', 1)
FROM your_table
```

Comment: I'm using sql server so this (SUBSTRING_INDEX) did not work for me, should work in mysql. Sorry about the incorrect tags; I've fixed them.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(columnname, 0, CHARINDEX('.', columnname)) from tablename